# Listvew with Edittext bottom size reduced on Keyboard open Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, keyboard, android-edittext

I have a problem with edit text size when keyboard open.
I have a list view and edit text in a activity. The edit text size is fine until keyboard open. After keyboard open the edit text height is reduced.

Case 1: Without Keyboard
[image]

Case 2: With Keyboard
[image]

My Layout code is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@color/screenBackGroundColor"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="@color/screenBackGroundColor"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="10" >

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/listView"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="8.8"
                android:clipToPadding="false"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp"
                android:fadeScrollbars="false"
                android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
                android:scrollbarSize="80.0dip"
                android:scrollbars="vertical"
                android:stackFromBottom="true"
                android:transcriptMode="normal" />

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editTextBarcode"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1.2"
                android:hint="Scan Product"
                android:inputType="text" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
```

What I already tried:
1.AdjustPan in maianifest file.

Comment: Did you try `android:layout_height="wrap_content"` without giving the weight for the `EditText`?

Comment: Thanks andro its working but now edit text is not at the bottom of screen while I need the edit text at bottom.

Comment: Because of the `weight`(1.2), it will always take 12% of your screen... try to increase the `weight` of your `EditText`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutMain"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:fadeScrollbars="false"
        android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
        android:scrollbarSize="80.0dip"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextBarcode"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Scan Product"
        android:inputType="text" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Weight fixes the height of your layout. So I removed them except for the `ListView` so that it covers remaining height.